# Replace image caption with its title and description

Tags: images, editor, captions

Is it possible to replace the caption text of an image with its title and description fields when inserting it in the editor? If so, how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi user1991185, could you provide more details on what you've tried already (and why it didn't work)?

Comment: I tried using the 'img_caption_shortcode' filter with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Unles I misunderstand the question, you can switch to the text editor after inserting the image and then manually edit the caption to put whatever you want in there.

Comment: Christopher, I'm sure the original poster, like me, would like to do this automatically when posting images.